# Order the result of query by collection size in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I'm trying to return the result of a HQL query as follows:

```
List<Parent> parents = 
currentSession().createQuery("from Parent order by count(children)").list();
```

So that the list is ordered by the bumber of children eadh parent has,
where children is an `ArrayList<Child>`.

I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed;
>       nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unknown column 'qualified' in 'order clause';
>       SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'qualified' in 'order clause'

It seems quite a simple query and exactly what the count method is for so I don’t really understand why it doesn't work. Also I don't know where the column 'qualified' is coming from or what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the problem like this.When i search in google for solution, i see your question in statckoverflow,and now you can reference with my case.

```
Class AEntity{

    @OneToMany
    Set<BEntity> bList;

}

HQL:from AEntity order by bList.size
```

Hope to help somebody like us.Thank you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [answer] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's pretty much standard SQL as I see it, so

```
"from Parent p left join p.children as pc group by p order by count(pc)"
```

is what I needed, however this gave an error due to it now returning tuples with an extra column, the number of children. This was fixed by specifying in the select clause that I wanted to return only the parent part of the joined table. I'm not exactly sure what was going on under the hood here but this works and make a nice logical and readable query.

```
"select p from Parent p left join p.children as pc group by p order by count(pc)"
```

simples.